# Чисто виртуальный класс и наследование

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть класс с таким содержимым:

```
class basic_client
{
public:
    basic_client() {}
    virtual void start();
    virtual void stop();
    virtual void do_write(const std::string & msg);
    virtual void sync_write(const std::string & msg);
    virtual ~basic_client() {}
};
```

И есть второй класс. Начало такое

```
class client : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<client>, boost::noncopyable,basic_client
```

Все виртуальные методы реализованы в классе client. Что он не хочет собиратся?

```
    main.o: In function `basic_client::basic_client()':
/home/gravit/code/build-boost-server-Desktop-Debug/../boost-server/main.hpp:19: undefined reference to `vtable for basic_client'
main.o: In function `basic_client::~basic_client()':
/home/gravit/code/build-boost-server-Desktop-Debug/../boost-server/main.hpp:24: undefined reference to `vtable for basic_client'
main.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI6client[_ZTI6client]+0x38): undefined reference to `typeinfo for basic_client'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Как правильно реализовать, что бы ошибки не было? Компилятор GCC

Comment: В классе `basic-client` реализованы не все виртуальные методы.

Comment: Они реализованы в классе client

Comment: Компилятор утверждает иное.

Comment: `void stop();
    void start();
    void do_read();
    void do_write(const std::string & msg);
    void sync_write(const std::string & msg);`

Comment: Виртуальный деструктор не реализован в `client`.

Comment: Сделал `virtual ~client();`. Ошибка осталась

Comment: `virtual ~client();` не реализация, а объявление. Сделайте `virtual ~client() { };`.

Comment: Деструктор реализован в cpp файле. Для экономии времени я не стал приводить код декструктора и написал только его объявление. Аналогично с всеми остальными функциями.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объявление вида

```
class A {
    virtual void f();
}
```

означает, что в классе `A` ***есть*** функция `f`, т.е. она не только объявлена, но и реализована. Похоже, что в Вашем случае есть только объявление, но нет реализации. Поэтому надо либо реализовать эту виртуальную функцию, либо указать компилятору, что её нет. Это так называемая ***чисто виртуальная*** функция и её объявление выглядит следующим образом:

```
class A {
    virtual void f() = 0;
}
```

Следует учесть, что класс `A` в этом случае становится ***абстрактным***, т.е. его экземпляр создать будет нельзя.

Comment: То что надо. Спасибо! Как раз нужна была чисто виртуальная функция

Comment: @kff помню когда только пошли `nullprt`, через одного пробовали писать `virtual void f() = nullptr;`, так смешно было )

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Действительно смешно! ))) Но, в общем-то логично. Функция-член по сути своей является указателем... Однако, вряд ли пишущие понимали такие тонкости.